# Azure pipeline cannot set variable for versioning in filename

Tags: bash, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run the following in azure pipeline to get the version of our web app from the php file.

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Get module version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      grep -i -E '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/file.php
      MODVER="$(grep -i -E '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rhipe.php | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d '\",')"
      echo $MODVER
      echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=ModuleVersion;]$MODVER
  name: GetModuleVersion

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Check module version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $(ModuleVersion)
      echo $(GetModuleVersion.ModuleVersion)
```

and I get the following response when I run the pipeline:

```
Starting: Check module version
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/79202ecb-a4bd-46af-ab77-ce5860253b3f.sh
/home/vsts/work/_temp/79202ecb-a4bd-46af-ab77-ce5860253b3f.sh: line 1: ModuleVersion: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/79202ecb-a4bd-46af-ab77-ce5860253b3f.sh: line 2: GetModuleVersion.ModuleVersion: command not found
```

I have tested the `MODVER` command on a bash terminal outside of azure and it seem to be working as expected.

**Update:**

I tried adding a script to check the variable value after the step to setup the variable, it also shows command not found.

Comment: with the check module version step, I also tried adding isOutput on get module version step hence the GetModuleVersion.ModuleVersion

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$(ModuleVersion)` can't be resolved when the inline script is being generated, because it doesn't exist yet. It's probably working fine in terms of setting the output variable, you just can't test it from the same script that generates it.

You can just print the variable in a second `script` step.

Comment: When I try to use `$(ModuleVersion)` for a filename it doesn't evaluate:

```
Task         : Archive files
Description  : Compress files into .7z, .tar.gz, or .zip
Version      : 2.215.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files
=====================================================================
Found 1 files
Archiving file: modules
files=modules
/usr/bin/zip -r /home/vsts/work/1/a/file-$(ModuleVersion).zip modules
```

Comment: I've also tried adding an additional bash step after setting the variable, to check the value of `$(ModuleVersion)` but it only shows me `ModuleVersion: command not found`